# Load Average too high.Top not showing much?How to find the process?

Tags: linux, debian, top

Debian 6.0 running on VPS with single core and 3 Gb RAM.

```
top - 09:24:19 up 17 days, 13:05,  2 users,  load average: 14.79, 16.19, 11.10
Tasks:  14 total,   1 running,  13 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.7%us, 24.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 55.0%id,  2.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  3.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3145728k total,   565144k used,  2580584k free,    10660k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4629  root      20   0 18932 1256 1004 S    0  0.0   1:06.59 top
    1  root      20   0  8356  728  680 S    0  0.0   5:55.67 init
 3295  root      20   0 73908 6884 2668 S    0  0.2   0:10.18 sshd
 3567  root      20   0 19300 2076 1520 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 bash
 3847  root      20   0 22420 1040  796 S    0  0.0   0:09.66 cron
 3895  root      20   0 70580 3460 2652 S    0  0.1   0:01.02 sshd
 4296  root      20   0 19300 2084 1524 S    0  0.1   0:00.05 bash
 6505 www-data   20   0  209m 7592 1216 S    0  0.2   0:00.00 apache2
 8005  root      20   0 18932 1256 1004 R    0  0.0   0:07.97 top
15546 www-data   20   0  209m 7628 1228 S    0  0.2   0:00.00 apache2
27765  root      20   0  208m  11m 5652 S    0  0.4   0:08.04 apache2
27929  root      20   0  3952  644  524 S    0  0.0   0:00.12 mysqld_safe
28161  mysql     20   0 5060m 506m 7180 S    0 16.5   4:05.89 mysqld
29551  root      20   0 49168 1164  616 S    0  0.0   0:00.10 sshd
```

top result showing process with 0.0% CPU usage

Why is the load average this much high. How can I figure out the process that is using too much CPU?

Comment: Your `top` listing doesn't appear to be sorted? Try sorting it by CPU usage. First press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then press <kbd>K</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: is that a needed thing ?coz load average is under 3 now?

Comment: Who says any process is using CPU?  There are a variety of reasons why the run queue could be large.

Comment: load average came down after taking screen shot...

Comment: cpu usage was showing 0 for every process

Answer (score 2):

Load average is calculated using processes which are either running, runnable or in uninterruptible sleep. Look for processes with state `D` in `ps` output. If you find some, you're likely facing I/O problems.

Answer (score 0):

Its not on your vserver If you can, check the other servers.